# Draw line dynamically basing from real time tracking geopoints

Tags: java, android, routes, drawing, overlay

I want to draw a line dynamically as the user turns anywhere he goes. I am struggling on how to draw the lines using the user geopoints as we listen to his location continuously. I have tried to use moveTo and lineTo but it's only possible for only one line. Thanks for your answers in advance thanks.!

Update:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mv, boolean shadow)
{
    Projection projection = mv.getProjection();
    ArrayList<GeoPoint> geoPoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    //Creating geopoints - ommited for readability
    Path p = new Path();
    for (int i = 0; i < geoPoints.size(); i++) {
    if (i == geoPoints.size() - 1) {
        break;
    }
    Point from = new Point();
    Point to = new Point();
    projection.toPixels(geoPoints.get(i), from);
    projection.toPixels(geoPoints.get(i + 1), to);
    p.moveTo(from.x, from.y);
    p.lineTo(to.x, to.y);
    }
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
    super.draw(canvas, mv, shadow);
}
```

Picture:

The drawing of line must follow wherever the user will be.
[image: draw track]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) and more specifically:

```
private final Path mPath;
................
mPath.lineTo(lastXCoord,lastYCoord);
```

Comment: Sir, thank you for answering can you provide a link for a related tutorial sir. I don't an advance background on making this code match my needs. I have added a code above and hope you can help me modify it, wherein I can draw not only one line but what ever the users positions will be must be the same line with it.

Comment: You are to keep the path as an instance field as implied by the above code snippet. You should not create it on every invocation of the draw() method. Create it in the constructor and only call mPath.lineTo(...) and canvas.drawPath(mPath); in the draw method. You can follow the link to the android documentation for the Path class to see what the lineTo method exactly does.